# How can I search through grails plugin sources

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I wanna search over linked plugin sources. How can I configure Idea to do it? Is it possible to make all grails dependencies / plugins searchable by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard `Find in Path` (`Control`+`Shift`+`F`) do search in plugin sources as well, if you select `Custom` scope with `Project and Libraries`

Comment: My project doesn't have any library from grails depenecies / plugins. This will correctly work with maven, but not with Grails

Comment: It's working with standard Grails projects as well. What version do you use?

Comment: Grails 2.0.3, Intellij 11.1. Can you send me working project with installed plugins, dependencies and Idea properties files?

Comment: Had same configuration (IDEA Ultimate, right?) - everything is working. Just opened project as a 'Grails Project'